# How do I exclude setTimeout or setInterval type statements when debugging with "Break on Next"?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with a large pre-existing codebase that may have one or more **setInterval**  timers running all the time, from various plug-ins or libraries. This basically makes it impossible to try to use **Break on Next** to debug what happens when I click on an element.

**Problem**: As soon as I click Break on Next, the browser debugger (tried with Firebug and Chrome) stops in one of the setInterval functions before I have a chance to interact with the page to really debug the event that I want.

**Specific problem**: I have checkboxes that stay unchecked when unchecked, no matter how many times I click on them. I've removed the ID and class names as well to no avail and appear to have no event handlers attached.

*Note: not using jQuery*

Comment: It's not a general solution, and may not even be sufficient for your case, but you could put a `debugger;` call in your click handler, so the debugger will activate when you click the checkbox. (This may not be sufficient if you don't know where the click handler is attached, or if there are multiple handlers.)

Comment: I do not know which handler is being called or from where... it could even be a parent element. That's why I want to use break-on-next in the browser, but not have the setInterval code getting in my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may brake other things, but what if you try to monkey-patch-out those calls like this:

```
window.setInterval = function() { console.log("setInterval", arguments); };
window.setTimeout = function() { console.log("setTimeout", arguments); };
```

If you find that some of timeouts/intervals are actually needed to reproduce your problem, you could try letting them through. Than the code could be something like:

```
window.oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function() { 
    if (arguments[0] == "code you want to allow") {
         oldSetTimeout.apply(null, arguments);
    } else {
         console.log("setTimeout", arguments); 
    }
};
```

Note: I wouldn't be suprised it monkey-patching setTimeout does not work cross-browser, but it works on FF 18.0

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a very good work around to stop (or at least delay) setIntervals, as long as I'm sure to place the monkey patch at the very top of the document.